# Encoding only spaces and commas in URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to encode a url in rails for an image attachment, but using CGI::escape or URI.escape seems to encode everything.  I just need the commas and spaces encoded, nothing else.  How would I go about doing that in rails?  I did gsub, but could only replace commas or spaces, not both.  Is there a way to do both?

```
http://"URL"?operation=getfieldclip&outlinePoints=600%2C600%2C400%2CTest Area%2C44.982643%2C-94.696723%2C44.982343%2C-94.696723%2C44.982293%2C-94.697170%2C44.982293%2C-94.697555%2C44.982313%2C-94.697740%2C44.982333%2C-94.697987%2C44.982363%2C-94.698110%2C44.982403%2C-94.698233%2C44.982453%2C-94.698341%2C44.982493%2C-94.698511%2C44.982553
```

I can get the commas changed, but not sure how to get the space changed at the same time as well.

Comment: If you are going to use it as a URL, then you need to encode other characters as well. Why do you want to leave other characters not encoded?

Comment: Because for some reason encoding the '&' or '?' will give me url that gives a 404.  Only encoding the commas and spaces after "outlinePoints" makes it work like it needs to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `CGI.escape`. Don't use it for the entire URL, but only for the values of it.

```
require "cgi"
"http://URL?" + params.map{|k, v| "#{k}=#{CGI.escape(v)}"}.join("&")
```

Comment: Okay, so currently the URL is set like this:
`url = "#{Settings.sei_gis_url}/ImageOps/imageop?operation=getfieldclip&outlinePoints=#{boundary}&drawnames=1"`

Where, the only stuff that should be encoded is #{boundary} which has spaces and commas. I'm no sure how I can use your solution for that.

Comment: `params = {"operation" => "getfieldclip", "outlinePoints" => boundary, "drawnames" => "1"}`